# How to burn fat and build muscle at the same time?

Tags: muscle, bodybuilding, bellyfat, fat

My cousin, whom is a professional bodybuilder suggested I start a diet plan.
I am  5' 8" tall and weigh 69 kilograms.
I want to build muscle and lose belly fat at the same time and was skeptical as to whether or not the diet he suggested would accomplish my goals.

Which brings me to my question, Will the diet I have listed below help me accomplish building Muscle and losing belly fat?

> Just after waking up 1 scoop([Isopure protein](http://www.gnc.com/whey-protein/IsopureLowCarb.html))  in cold water 30
>   mins hiit aerobics or anything without weights Nothing to have for
>   next 1 hr except water
>
> BreakFast(4 eggs full. Either boiled or cooked in butter) 1 bowl
>   oatmeal
>
> 15 Almonds ( peel them off n consume after being left in water last
>   night) 1 banana In lunch have half plate of rice with water removed
>   during cooking n have chicken with it as u wish... Cooked in olive oil
>   or butter After 2 hours have some green veggies as per ur taste 5 pm
>   have a green tea
>
> an Apple in evening
>
> Before going to gym - have a cup of black coffee... In warm water
>   without sugar After gym take 3 slices of white bread plus a protein
>   shake in water
>
> Before sleeping have 3 pieces of thigh( No roti/rice)
>
> Before sleeping 1 bowl of papaya -  excretion purpose
>
> Few Points-
>
> Multivitamins - Fish oil to be take before sleeping... Around 3gm Buy
>   a box of creatine monohydrate, to be consumed with the acoop of
>   protein poweder at night Only time when u won't be taking butter is
>   just after the exercise No Milk (Instead u ll take a calcium tab
>   daily) No Curd  Have yogurt
>
> Berries, Avacado,Strawberries, Blueberries and other non-tropical
>   fruits can be taken alongside.

Kindly suggest as to whether the above mentioned plan is a good one.

Comment: This question needs more information added to it. Such as what body type you are? You are a healthy weight for your height and muscle does weigh more then fat. What kind of workout routine are you doing besides the 30 minute HIIT? You did mention the gym but no mention what you are doing at the GYM? or how often you are going to the GYM. Diet and Gym go hand in hand.I am afraid this question can not be fully answered without adding more content to it.